# Vuejs - How to set the default value of a prop to a predefined data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

The question is simple. I want to define a `data` as follows;

```
data() {
  return {
    logoURL: "some-link/some-picture.png"
  }
}
```

and I want to set it to a prop's default state like this:

```
props: {
  infoLogoURL: {
    type: String,
    default: this.logoURL,
  },
}
```

Apparently it doesn't work the way I want and I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logoURL' of undefined
```

How can I manage this? Here is an example of how I use my props:

```
<cardComp
  infoTitle = "Info Title" 
  infoText = "Info Text" 
  infoSubIcon = "Sub Icon Name" 
  infoSubIconColor = "css-color-class" 
  infoSubText = "Sub Text" 
  infoDescription = "Some Text Description" 
  infoIcon = "Icon Name" 
  infoIconColor = "icon-color-css"
  infoLogoURL = "some-link/some-picture.png"
/>
```

And here is another question... I want to display `infoIcon` when there is no `infoLogoURL`. So let's say the link of that specific .png file is not available in a moment of time, so in that case, I want to display the `infoIcon`. When the .png file is available, I should only display the `infoLogoURL`, not the `infoIcon`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can't set the default value of a prop from `data`.

One way around this is to use a `computed` property instead:

```js
computed: {
  defaultLogoURL: function() {
    return this.infoLogoURL || this.logoURL
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! I'll try this one and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `computed` property that returns the value of the `prop` "info_logo_url" when set, and that of `data` "logoURL" when not.

Concerning the second part of the question, another `computed` property can be defined to return the `prop` "info_logo_url" when set, and that of the `prop` "info_icon" when not.

```js
const cardcomponent = Vue.component('card-component', {
  template: '#card-component',
  data(){
    return { logoURL: "some-link/some-picture.png" }
  },
  props: {
    info_logo_url: { type: String },
    info_icon: { type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    myInfoLogo() { return this.info_logo_url || this.logoURL; },
    myInfoIcon() { return this.info_logo_url || this.info_icon; },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { cardcomponent },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <cardcomponent info_logo_url="info logo URL" info_icon="info icon"/>
  </div><hr>
  <div>
    <cardcomponent info_logo_url="info logo URL"/>
  </div><hr>
  <div>
    <cardcomponent info_icon="info icon"/>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="card-component">
  <div>
    <b>myInfoLogo</b>: {{myInfoLogo}} - <b>myInfoIcon</b>: {{myInfoIcon}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try to use the computed  tomorrow and let you know if it's okay.